# Android app crash some devices if compile with Android App Bundle Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-app-bundle

When i compile my app with Android App bundle and start on Xiaomi my app is crash, but if i start on Samsung app not crash. And if i don't compile my app with android app bundle, my app workd well.

```
00 pc 0000000000042058 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 000000000003fc65 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
#02 pc 000000000001c403 /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00000000000195b5 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
#04 pc 0000000000017508 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 0000000000333b29 /system/lib/libart.so (ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+228)
#06 pc 00000000000f48bb /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+2226)
#07 pc 000000000025ab2d /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2+1552)
#08 pc 000000000025af5b /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+74)
#09 pc 00000000002838b9 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI20CallStaticIntMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+468)
#10 pc 000000000000ad4f /data/app/com.Creator.App-1/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk
#11 pc 000000000000a170
```

Comment: What Xiaomi device? What Android version?

Comment: Xiaomi MI 4LTE (cancro), Android 6.0

Comment: Fix https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/168633/app-crash#latest

Comment: @DiamondKesha If solved ,remember to share it in answer , then can mark it .